# Passing one class to another class using a constructor

Tags: java

First of all, I have 3 Classes. The Main class is named 'main', a runnable called StartRunnable, and another runnable called Elimination Runnable.

EliminationRunnable runs on a constant loop, as long as the current game is active through a variable

StartRunnable runs on a for loop with many thread.sleeps to execute different stuff, and the for loop has a counter called "intCounterLoop". It is declared as public.

Main Class creates a new instance of each runnable at the same time.

```
new Thread(new StartRunnable()).start();
new Thread(new EliminationRunnable(args[1])).start();
```

**Now, the problem**

How can I access the intCounterLoop variable from the StartRunnable Class; in the EliminationRunnable Class without using Static? I cannot use static as multiple instances of these classes might be going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your StartRunnable instance in a variable instead of constructing it right there in that parameter list.

Then just pass the instance as a parameter to your EliminationRunnable constructor. That's what variables are for.

```
StartRunnable s = new StartRunnable();
new Thread(s).start();
new Thread(new EliminationRunnable(args[1], s)).start();
```

Then you can access any public stuff you want as necessary.

PS You could leave the field public and access it directly but I'd make it private and go for a public getter and setter instead. You can find arguments for that pretty easily on the internet if you want to dig deeper. In any case how you want to expose access to it is outside the scope of this answer.